# set PDF field read only using XFA

Tags: pdf, itext, xfa

How can I set field "read only" in PDF using XFA and iTextSharp? I know that I have to modify the XML, but I don't know which attribute/value to set.

```
var attr = xfa.DomDocument.CreateAttribute("fflags");
attr.Value = "1";
xfa.DomDocument.GetElementsByTagName("my_field")[0].Attributes.Append(attr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used iTextSharp but the attribute in XFA that you are looking for is the `access` attribute on the field. And the value is "readOnly".

```
<field access="readOnly">
```

will make the field read only.